# Turning player direction without speeding up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I'm trying to make a small prototype of a tribes-like game, mainly inspired by Tribes:Ascend. The problem is that the movement is hard to make.
Skiing, which is sliding frictionless on the ground to maintain speed, is no problem. Air/ski control on the other hand is.
What I'm trying to do is to let the player change direction or slow down when at high speeds without speeding up in any way.

This is the script I'm using for this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public  Transform cameraObj;
    public Transform cameraRefObj;
    public Transform velObj;
    public  Camera cameraCam;
    public  Rigidbody rigbod;
    public  CapsuleCollider cap;
    public float maxVel;

    public float walkForce;
    public float defDynFric;
    public float defStatFric;
    void Start () {
        rigbod = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cap = this.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        cameraObj = this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform;
        cameraCam = this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    }
    
    void Update () {
        Vector3 vel = rigbod.velocity;
        Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, vel);
        Vector3 velCalc = new Vector3(vel.x, 0, vel.z);
        float speedCapMult =Mathf.Clamp01(vel.magnitude / maxVel);
        velObj.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(velCalc);
        cameraRefObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.EulerAngles(0, Quaternion.ToEulerAngles(cameraObj.rotation).y, 0);
        if (Input.GetButton("Skii"))
        {
            cap.material.dynamicFriction = 0;
            cap.material.staticFriction = 0;
        } else
        {
            cap.material.dynamicFriction = defDynFric;
            cap.material.staticFriction = defStatFric;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") !=0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            Vector3 InputVec = Quaternion.EulerAngles(0, Quaternion.ToEulerAngles(cameraObj.rotation).y, 0) * Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") ),1);
            float moveMulti =(1 -speedCapMult) +(speedCapMult*Mathf.Clamp01(1-Mathf.Cos(Vector3.Angle(velCalc, InputVec)/2)));
            InputVec = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(InputVec, moveMulti);
            Vector3 resVec = InputVec * (moveMulti * walkForce);
            
            Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, resVec, Color.red);
           // Debug.Log("SPD*: "+speedCapMult + "  moveMulti: " + moveMulti + "  VecAng: "+ Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Cos((Vector3.Angle(velCalc, InputVec)/2)-1)));
            rigbod.AddForce(resVec);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is from what I understand mainly with this line:

```
 float moveMulti =(1 -speedCapMult) +(speedCapMult*Mathf.Clamp01(1-Mathf.Cos(Vector3.Angle(velCalc, InputVec)/2)));
```

What it does is transition between low speed movement to highspeed movement. Low speed is fine up the high speed movement isn't working as intended. When turning the velocity direction only turns a small bit and then it stops and the player continues to travel that direction unless I turn the camera (Somewhat similar to surfing in source games).

I want it to work like it does in T:A. I cant really find any good reference video, but the gist of it is that you can go to the side, slow down but not speed up.

Comment: I suppose you could use `rigbod.AddTorque` instead to change only the angular velocity and not the linear velocity. See the [Documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Its so simple i feel silly.
I simply changed the movemultiplier to:

```
            float moveMulti =(1 -speedCapMult) +(speedCapMult*Mathf.Clamp01(Vector3.Angle(velCalc, InputVec)/180));
```

Basically ditching the cosign thing to a simple angle. Its works as intended now.